# COM CLASS FACTORY

Tags: asp.net

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {86A3FE22-515C-45BF-B489-07DEEB03E2D6} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
this is error message in my page in asp.net?
pls help me how can i remove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error code means that your COM component is not correctly registered.

I assume that your ASP code is relying on the COM component with CLSID {86A3FE22-515C-45BF-B489-07DEEB03E2D6}. Try to figure out which COM object belongs to this id and register it (using regsvr32 or regasm).

Comment: but i unable to find the COM object

Comment: Where in your code does the error occur? If possible generate and deploy the .pdb files as well as this will tell you the exact line number.

Comment: ya this indicate the line no but i m unable to find out that which registry is used by this code.pls give me suggestion that how can i open dll file means can i open the dll file if yes then in which format

Comment: Can you update your question and show the piece of code throwing the error?

Comment: i have got the line number,but in this line i don't under stand the error.

Comment: @picnic4u: Sorry, but without seeing the actual code I'm afraid I won't be able to provide any more help.